# How to download a file from one server to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to download a file from one server to another for e.g suppose I have 2 server 1.api server and 2.test server

**in test server**

```
downloadFile(req, res) {
  let file = path.join(__dirname, "../config/config.js");
  res.status(200).send("http://ip-address:port" + file);
}
```

**in api server**

```
  const http = require('http');
  const path = require('path'); 
  HttpDownload(req,res) {

        let file = fs_file.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "temp", "output.js"));
        http.get(url-to-test-server, function (response) {
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                file.write(chunk)
            })
            response.on('end', function () {
                console.log('download file completed.')
                res.download(path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "temp", "output.js"))
            })
        })
}
```

can anybody suggest me what I am doing wrong ?? Thank in advance.

Comment: _“can anybody suggest me what I am doing wrong ??”_ - you completely neglected to give us an actual problem description here. (And before you say “doesn’t work” now, please go read [ask].)